# image can't be decoded

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal image loader.It is working fine but not decoding few images.

logcat error -Decode returned false
image can't be decoded.

please find below the sample code for the same.

```
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showStubImage(R.drawable.iphoneicon_small).cacheInMemory()
                    .cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
                    .build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration imgconfig = ImageLoaderConfiguration
                    .createDefault(activity);

    imageLoader.init(imgconfig);

    imageURL = contacts.get(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.LOGO_IMAGE);

    imageLoader.displayImage(Utils.getEncodedUrl(imageURL),
                holder.image_logo_icon, options);
```

In my getview there should be five images but it is loading 3 images and two default image that i set and not from web server.